# How to find a vector representation for each descriptor?

Tags: classification, descriptive-statistics, semantic-similarity, vector-space-models, context-vector

[Cubes data](https://www.kaggle.com/code/venkateshkulkarni11/classification-using-concept-vectors) is well known data for extreme classification. Each picture has a set of descriptor along with it. Total data set has 312 descriptor. You will find list of descriptior in [this file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZkBV0hfnnxqjymmKiet-Cdh_qJ-9CQ7ruVgUopiFCs8/edit?usp=sharing).

My question is how to find a vector representation for each descriptor so that similarity in vectors reflect the semantic similarity of descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get started would be to simply call Word2Vec or Glove to get embeddings for the descriptors, and then refine from there. https://www.kaggle.com/code/pierremegret/gensim-word2vec-tutorial is a good starting point that covers training. You can just start with pretrained vectors, something like

```
glove_vectors = gensim.downloader.load('glove-wiki-gigaword-100')
```

Then you'll need to split your descriptors into individual words, getting rid of underscores, "-", etc. Once you have a list of words per descriptor, you can get the average embeddings with code like

```
words = ['upper', 'tail', 'color', 'orange']
mean_vec = glove_vectors.get_mean_vector(words)
```

And then use the mean_vec to determine similarity (e.g. cosine distance) from other embeddings.

Comment: Please give one example code.

Comment: Please elaborate little, I am struggling to understand.

Comment: What are you struggling to understand? What have you tried so far? Please post your code and your current results and that will allow this forum to help you more.

Comment: I need to small code and it's intended output. I am very new on this topic.

Comment: Could you write little bit more explanation and show the output of the vector representation. Then it will be more clear to me. Please.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to find the average of the word embeddings of each token in each descriptor. A pretrained word embedding model would be a useful way to start.

Here is a rough start in Python:

```py
import gensim
import gensim.downloader
from gensim.utils import tokenize

# Pretrained word embedding model
model = gensim.downloader.load('glove-wiki-gigaword-300')

# Sample descriptor from CUB 200 2011 dataset
descriptor = "this bird has a short orange bill, white breast" 
# Split into tokens 
tokens = list(tokenize(descriptor)) 
# Create mean vector embedding of tokens
vector = model.get_mean_vector(tokens)
```

Comment: I am not able to print out anything! Please help.